# How do I programmatically update pathauto paths for an entity?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

If an entity has opted into auto generated paths, you could simply re-save the entity. However saving an entity is particularly inefficient, and the path/routing system runs outside of the entity system.

How do I update a path for an entity without saving the entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `pathauto.generator` service provided by Pathauto:

```
\Drupal::service('pathauto.generator')->updateEntityAlias($entity, 'update');
```